# Does google penalizes if there is random posts display

Tags: seo, google-search, wordpress

Using wordpress theme that displays related posts on single post. Every time I refresh the page I see different results for related posts.

Does google penalize the web-page that displays different related posts every time the page is refreshed?

Comment: Short answer? No.

Comment: Users might through... they might see something, refresh and bang its gone!

Comment: Simon is perfectly right! There is some user experience (UX) danger to a page such as described. As well, I am not sure the page would yield too much value in search. Penalty? No. Good idea? No. Cheers!!

Comment: If the page yields about 15 posts then how google behaves? Also! after the page is refreshed the specific post may disappear if user come back to the page for that post.  Doe

Answer (score 1):

No. This happens on publisher sites all the time, the "top news" story carousel/ link module (whatever you want to call it) updates constantly.

However, if you're looking for static crawl paths, i.e. ensuring you have internal links to said articles, this rotational system is unreliable.

To ensure you have static crawl paths, supplement your rotating related posts widget links with an HTML sitemap at least.